# How to use Soundex with SQLITE in android

Tags: android, sqlite, soundex

Could someone please guide me on how to use soundex in sqlite. or can we use "soundex" function in sqlite.
if we can use it Please provide an example if possible.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You use it just like any other SQL function. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @CL. Currently if i search for example 'chir' then 'chair' won't show on the results. I want you to find out the "computer" result when I search for "compuzer". I use the like command when searching in sql query. but that is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [soundex() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#soundex) would have to be enabled with the [SQLITE_SOUNDEX compile-time option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#soundex).
The Android framework does not do this.